# Ruby on Rails - Float variable IF statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, types, integer

I don't know if it's "normal" but whenever I want to use my variables in statements I need to convert them into integer/float even if I declare them as integer/float. Am I doing something wrong or is it just the way that Ruby works ? Thanks

For example, my declarations :

```
  Struct.new("Pack", :id, :qty, :promo, :reduction)
  @@pack1 = Struct::Pack.new(1, 10, 0, 0.1)
  @@pack2 = Struct::Pack.new(2, 25, 0, 0.1)
  @@pack3 = Struct::Pack.new(3, 50, 5, 0.1)
  @@pack4 = Struct::Pack.new(4, 100, 10, 0.1)

  def self.packs
    [0, @@pack1, @@pack2, @@pack3, @@pack4]
  end
```

Let's take `reduction` for this example. When I use them it is not recognize as float even if I declare them as 0.1 without `" "`. **Doesn't enter** in IF statement:

```
def my_function(pack_id)
  reduction = MyModel.packs[pack_id].reduction
  Rails.logger.debug reduction   # Print 0.1
  if reduction > 0.0
    # Some stuff
  end
end
```

IF statement is working :

```
def my_function(pack_id)
  reduction = MyModel.packs[pack_id].reduction.to_f
  Rails.logger.debug reduction   # Print 0.1
  if reduction > 0.0
    # Some stuff
  end
end
```

For information :

```
2.1.3 :001 > MyModel.packs
 => [0, #<struct Struct::Pack id=1, qty=10, promo=0, reduction=0.1>, #<struct Struct::Pack id=2, qty=25, promo=0, reduction=0.1>, #<struct Struct::Pack id=3, qty=50, promo=5, reduction=0.1>, #<struct Struct::Pack id=4, qty=100, promo=10, reduction=0.1>] 
2.1.3 :002 > MyModel.packs[1].reduction
 => 0.1 
2.1.3 :003 > MyModel.packs[1].reduction.type
NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for 0.1:Float
```

---

EDIT :

The main difference seams here, I can't explain why right now.
When my application is running :

```
Rails.logger.debug MyModel.packs[1].reduction.class # Fixnum
```

In rails console :

```
2.1.3 :012 >   MyModel.packs[1].reduction.class
 => Float
```

Comment: Hm. It can't be true.

Comment: `MyModel.packs[1].reduction > 0.0`?

Comment: Hi @fl00r, do you see some errors on my code about that ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
MyModel.packs[1].reduction.class
```

In your debugging, ruby doesn't have types, almost everything is an object, including numbers.